# Как проверить количество запросов к базе?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Написал это, и оно работает... но как проверить, что соединение постоянное, а не обычное? да, должно работать... но всё бывает...

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: не вижу тут ничего постоянного. когда $dbh становится null подключение закрывается

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Да, по приведенной вами ссылки прямо так и сказано: "_При успешном подключении к базе данных в скрипт будет возвращен созданный объект PDO. Соединение остается активным на протяжении всего времени жизни объекта. Чтобы закрыть соединение, необходимо уничтожить объект путем удаления всех ссылок на него (этого можно добиться, присваивая NULL всем переменным_". Вы как раз присваиваете NULL единственному указателю на объект, так что соединение закроется. Так что объясните, что вы понимаете под "постоянное подключение"

Comment: соединение не должно открываться много раз, если есть-использовать его...ибо это под сокет будет...

Comment: ну во время выполнения запроса оно конечно не может закрыться. но у вас тут запрос, который когда нибудь заканчивается, $dbh становится null и соединение закрывается. Вы вообще не должны открывать соединение непосредственно перед выполнением запроса. Сделайте свой класс, который при любом обращении будет создавать соединение, но только в том случае если он этого еще не делал. Т.е. надо сохранять указатель на объект соединения в более долгоживущей переменной, чем доступной в одной функции, например в переменной члене класса

Comment: Я так и сделаю, но для этого мне надо понять, будет ли это работать(брать это за основу)? фан сокета в том, что соединение надо закрывать только при событие onclose, остальное продолжительное время(минуты, часы, сутки) соединение должно находится в постоянном режиме для режима сообщений

Comment: Что именно вы из приведенного примера собрались брать за основу. Первая строка создает соединение, пока последняя переменная его содержащая не уйдет из областей видимости и не будет затерта соединение будет работать. Правда его может разорвать сам MySQL или какой нибудь сбой сети. Но это уже другая история, конечно после любых пауз стоит проверять живо ли все еще соединение и если оно разорвалось создавать его заново.

Comment: Для того чтобы соединение было постоянное, нужно как минимум указать это в коде. Указать значение 4-го параметра в PDO  `[PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true]`